# Problem with ADVERTISED_LISTENER on macos

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kcat

I start kafka with this `docker-compose.yml` on my Mac:

```
 mydb:
 [...]
   environment: 
     kafka_bootstrap_servers: kafka:9093

 kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.6.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "mytopic:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      #KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERN://:9093,LISTENER_EXTERN://127.0.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERN://:9093,LISTENER_EXTERN://127.0.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERN:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERN:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_EXTERN

      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I have two LISTENER because there is a second container `mydb` that does not work with the `PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092` listener.

In fact, using

```
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

works with `kafkacat`. But then the other container can`t connect to kafka.

Now I want to connect to kafka via

```
kafkacat -b 127.0.0.1:9092 -t mytopic -L
```

but it gives this error

```
%6|1605191095.939|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 
127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: 
Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration 
(connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 2ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
```

the `debug` log for the broker is:

```
%7|1605191334.678|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1605191334.678|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1605191334.678|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1605191334.678|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1605191334.678|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.5.0 (0x10500ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, CC CXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2)
%7|1605191334.678|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1605191334.678|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1605191334.678|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1605191334.678|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1605191334.678|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: leader query
%7|1605191334.678|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1605191334.678|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 (plaintext) with socket 7
%7|1605191334.679|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092
%7|1605191334.679|CONNECTED|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1605191334.679|FEATURE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1605191334.679|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1605191334.679|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1605191334.681|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 2ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY) (_TRANSPORT)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with your particular example, and couldn't get it to work.

For what it's worth, [this Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-ecosystem/docker-compose.yml#L1-L45) is how I run Kafka on Docker locally, and it's accessible both from the host machine, and other containers.

You might find [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc) useful if you want to continue with your existing approach and debug it further.

Comment: Great! Works now. I used your setup and - I think this was the point - not the `wurstmeister` image.

Comment: Same, worked for us. We swapped out the `debezium/kafka` image to make it work with a local python application: 9092 for python on the host, 29092 for internal docker network (connect etc).

Answer (score 1):

You've only set the extern listener to bind internal to the container and not allow remote connections

You'd need

```
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERN://kafka:9093,LISTENER_EXTERN://0.0.0.0:9092
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERN://kafka:9093,LISTENER_EXTERN://127.0.0.1:9092
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERN:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERN:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERN
```